# Unexpected result with subselect in polymorphic relation

Tags: mysql, polymorphic-associations, mysql-8.0

Can someone explain why i get such strange result with these two queries, because i cant figure out by my self.

Mysql version: 8.0.18

I tested this in two absolutely different machines with same Mysql version(Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 20.04)

There is two tables:

products:

```
| id | name      |
|----|-----------|
| 1  | product 1 | 
| 2  | product 2 |
| 3  | product 3 |
| 4  | product 4 |
```

comments:

```
| id | commentable_id | commentable_type | content | confirmed_at        |
|----|----------------|------------------|---------|---------------------|
| 1  | 1              | Product          | test    | 2020-11-02 01:00:00 |
| 2  | 1              | Product          | test    | 2020-11-02 01:00:00 |
| 3  | 2              | Product          | test    | 2020-11-02 01:00:00 |
| 4  | 2              | Product          | test    | 2020-11-02 01:00:00 |
| 5  | 3              | Product          | test    | null                |
| 6  | 4              | Product          | test    | 2020-11-02 01:00:00 |
| 7  | 4              | Product          | test    | 2020-11-02 01:00:00 |
```

With this SQL query everything works just fine:

```sql
SELECT 
    `id`,
    (SELECT 
           COUNT(*)
        FROM
            `comments`
        WHERE
            `products`.`id` = `comments`.`commentable_id`
                AND `comments`.`commentable_type` = 'Product'
                AND `comments`.`confirmed_at` is not null
        ) AS `comments_count`
FROM
    `products`
WHERE
    `id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Result:

```
| id | comments_count |
|----|----------------|
| 1  | 2              | 
| 2  | 2              |
| 3  | 0              |
| 4  | 2              |
```

With this SQL query i get very strange result:

```sql
SELECT 
    `id`,
    (SELECT 
           COUNT(*)
        FROM
            `comments`
        WHERE
            `products`.`id` = `comments`.`commentable_id`
                AND `comments`.`commentable_type` = 'Product'
                AND `comments`.`confirmed_at` is not null
        LIMIT 1) AS `comments_count`
FROM
    `products`
WHERE
    `id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Result:

```
| id | comments_count |
|----|----------------|
| 1  | 2              | 
| 2  | 2              |
| 3  | 0              |
| 4  | 0              |
```

[Mysql workbench recorded](https://youtu.be/OcT1T5y36dY)

Comment: Both `DISTINCT` and `LIMIT` make no sense in this context. You have a scalar subquery (ie: that always returns 1 row).

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e5f204f6e16a7547c3811367d418371d and https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4EDpKVzE89sCmcsLxMgvmT/0

Comment: Sorry, there shoul not be `DISTINCT` i removed it(i was trying different scenarios ant forgot to remove `DISTINCT`). I know that there shoul not be `LIMIT 1`, i just trying to figue out, why Mysql return such strange result. Could it be related with mysql setup or something else ? Because in other machines everyting works as expected.

Comment: I entered all your data and tested your two queries. They return identical results given the example data above. I suggest you have an issue with some other query that you have not shown, or with some different data that you have not shown.

Comment: I have just recorded video: [https://youtu.be/OcT1T5y36dY](https://youtu.be/OcT1T5y36dY)